# how to get the result of query inside <sql:query> using jsp

Tags: java, jsp

```
**<sql:query dataSource="${con}" var="day" >
Select to_char(to_date('30-Nov-16','dd-mon-yy'), 'DAY') FROM DUAL
</sql:query>**
```

in the above i tried to get day of the week using SQL. but i was unable to get the result of query. please any body help me to get result of query. if it there any other solution for this help me.

Comment: What do you mean "i was unable to get the result of query?"  How would you know if you had it?  What, specifically, isn't working?

Comment: if execute query "Select to_char(to_date('30-Nov-16','dd-mon-yy'), 'DAY') FROM DUAL" in sql its working fine. i am getting the result as "wednesday". how to retrieve the same result in JSP.

Comment: How do you know you aren't getting it?  Where is the rest of your page?  Specifically, where are you using the `day` variable?